# UILabel how to autofit content?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm working on a personal project which is a simple quote generator.

Users can save favourite their quotes to a list, and in the list view I would like the UILabel to size responsively to the content (some quotes are short, and some are long - which can look a bit odd).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
UILabel *favouriteLabel;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        favouriteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -10, 400, 140)];
    }else {
        favouriteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -20, 180, 130)];
    }
    favouriteLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    favouriteLabel.text = [self.arrayFromFile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Row alloc %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Load label %@", favouriteLabel.text);
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        favouriteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Eras Bold ITC" size: 18];
    }else if([GUIHelper  isPhone5]){
        favouriteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Dosis-Medium" size: 15];
    }
    else
        favouriteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Dosis-Medium" size: 15];
    favouriteLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:68.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    favouriteLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    favouriteLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    favouriteLabel.center = CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 40, cell.center.y + 20);
     favouriteLabel.tag = 900;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:favouriteLabel];

    UIImage *lineImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"quote-divider@2x.png"];
    CGRect lineImageFrame;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        lineImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 120, lineImg.size.width, lineImg.size.height);
    }else{
        lineImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 62, lineImg.size.width * 0.9, 0.8*lineImg.size.height);
    }
    UIImageView *lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:lineImageFrame];
    lineImageView.image = lineImg;
    lineImageView.center = CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 40, lineImageView.center.y + 35);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you add the label to the view, try `[favoriteLabel sizeToFit]`.